# Security concerns for hosting a .NET website

Tags: security

Is the default configuration of Windows Server 2003 with IIS 6 and .NET 4 sufficient for security if I keep up to date with security updates? (assuming my code does not create any security holes).

Comment: There is no "sufficent" with security. It's like asking if your home is secure enough. Nothing is secure against someone who has the right tools to break in. security.stackoverflow.com is the place for finding out ways to "harden" Server 2003, e.g. http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1992/windows-hardening